# Get all passed-in attrs from an Ember Component

Tags: ember.js

Is it possible to get all attrs defined in an Ember component? E.g. if someone uses it like this

```
{{my-datepicker one='option' another='option' ... }}
```

in the component code can I grab or iterate over all the options that were passed in?

I believe this is going to be much simpler with block params + other forthcoming improvements, but is there a hacky way to do this right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a will - there is gotta to be a way. You asked for hacky :)

```
App.XHackComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  didInsertElement: function(){
    var source = this._keywords.view.source;

    var exceptions = ["helperName", "templateData", "container", "elementId", 
                      "currentState", "classNames", "classNameBindings", "controller",
                      "toString", "buffer", "element"];

    for (var key in source) {
      if(key.charAt(0) === "_") continue;
      if (source.hasOwnProperty(key) && !exceptions.contains(key)) {
       console.log("Key: " + key + ", Value: " + source[key]);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Working example [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sesavo/1/edit?html,js,console)

Comment: thanks :) Any way to get in *arbitrary* passed in attrs?

Comment: again, I know this will be super simple soon, because all props passed in will live under `attrs` key

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *arbitrary*. When I think of *arbitrary*, I think of "any number of attributes with any names" which my solution satisfies (with minor exceptions like underscores and reserved attribute names). The hard-coded **exceptions** are all the stuff I am *excluding*.

Comment: Ah woops, looked at this too quickly + it was late! Thanks a lot!